# How do I install and play the Day Z mod for Arma 2?

Tags: arma-2, dayz-2012

I'd like to install and play the *Day Z* mod for *Arma 2*, but the web page for the mod doesn't give very specific instructions. Simply dropping the .rar files into the specified directories seems to be insufficient.

I'd like a step by step process for installing and launching this mod. I purchased the game through Steam, if distribution method matters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This process has gotten a lot simpler since the question was originally asked.

The DayZ site now [recommends](https://twitter.com/dayzdevteam/status/213265856757628929) and [links a launcher](http://dayzmod.com/?SixUpdater) which installs the mod, updates it, and even lets you launch the game from it. Turns the entire process into a few simple clicks, and has the stamp of approval from the DayZ team so that you don't have to worry about running an unsupported executable.

For DayZ to run, you need both *Arma II* and its expansion, *Operation Arrowhead* (which you have if you've purchased *Arma 2: Combined Operation*).

Comment: Does this work for [the free version](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/77626) of ARMA II as well?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not in a good position to find out, either, sadly.

Comment: I can confirm that this **does** work with ARMA II free as well.  Just make sure you follow [these directions](http://kodabar.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-install-dayz-with-arma-2-free.html) *(particularly, steps 3 and 4 - you can skip step 5, the launcher does that for you)*.  I also had to verify my game cache after everything was done to get it to work, a problem a lot of people are having apparently.

Answer (score 15):

I just got this working myself, although it took some help from the internet to get it working.

- Install **Arma 2** and **Arma 2: Operation Arrowhead.**
- Close Steam completely, and then rerun it as an administrator (this is required to launch Arma 2 for the first time. You'll get a bad serial key error otherwise)
- Create folder called **@DayZ** in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\arma 2 operation arrowhead`
- Create a folder inside of that folder called **Addons**, and then download all the DayZ mod files from the [DayZ website](http://www.dayzmod.com/) into that folder *(So they should be located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\arma 2 operation arrowhead\@DayZ\Addons`)*
- Extract the files into the Addons folder. Make sure they are in the top level of the Addons folder or Arma 2 won't be able to find the files.
- Launch **Arma 2** (you need to run Arma 2 first in order for Arma 2: Combined Operations to work, which is required for DayZ.
- Launch **Arma 2: Operation Arrowhead** from the Steam library, and run it as **Arma 2: Combined Operation**

That's all you'll need to do to get DayZ working. Chances are you'll want to filter out the non-DayZ games, which you can do by opening the Filter menu and setting mission to **DayZ**.

Sources: [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjWFv1CUa6Y), [this thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?s=135fd738bd990a1aff988bb7bf24c152&t=1335248&page=2), and [this thread](http://forums.bistudio.com/showthread.php?117997-Resolved-ArmA-II-Steam-Version-Bad-serial-number-given-in-setup).

Comment: So Operation Arrowhead required for the mod to work? Dang!

Comment: @Sterno According to the mods website it is.

Comment: This didn't work for me until I copied the mod files to the base `Arma 2/Addons` Folder.

Comment: I see. For me they had to be located in the Operation OVerhead folder. I know you bought both games separately, so maybe that's part of the issue?

Comment: They'oll only be in 'C:\Program Files (x86)' if you're on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: Also see http://www.reddit.com/r/dayz/comments/ttqdm/having_trouble_installing_the_game/

Answer (score 4):

I made a launcher and updater because I was fed up with these convoluted and hard ways of doing things.  Install is just a case of running the launcher, will download the mod and launch Arma2 with all the correct parameters, for retail and Steam versions.  If no updates are available, will launch into the game straight away.

The download and description [is available here](http://www.richardbenson.co.uk/2012/05/dayz-launcher-and-updater.html).

Comment: Does this work for [the free version](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/77626) of ARMA II as well?

Answer (score 1):

Just watch this guide from xlNewbeelx he explains it real good

Answer (score 1):

I used a different method of installing, I followed this guide:

It is pretty simple and everything seems to be working fine.