# Differences between Arma 2 Free and Arma 2 Demo

Tags: steam, arma-2

Trying to find more information about the DayZ mod, I learnt that the base game (Arma 2) appears to have 2 different 'free' versions, one enticingly labeled as 'Arma 2 Free' and also a seperate 'Demo' - however neither the official site nor Steam helped me figure out why anyone would go for the demo version.

To make things more confusing, the Steam download link for Arma 2 Free says 'Download Demo'. I'm aware that demo release was 2009 and Arma 2 Free was 2011; and the features [not included in the free version](http://www.arma2.com/free).

So, what is the demo - and does the Steam download for Arma 2 Free actually install just the demo or the full 'Free' version that I could get from the developer's site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this page](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=851573), the free version is mislabeled as a demo.  So the "demo" is actually the free-version.

The difference between ARMA II and ARMA II Free is that Free has lower quality audio/textures, and doesn't have the single-player campaign.

Also, according to [this page](http://kodabar.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-install-dayz-with-arma-2-free.html), **ARMA II Free can be used to play DayZ Mod** *(you still need to purchase ARMA II: Operation Arrowhead)*.  That page also confirms that you get ARMA II Free using the "Download Demo" button in Steam:

[image: Arma II Free]

Users on [this page](http://www.joystiq.com/2012/07/12/over-500k-attempting-to-survive-in-arma-2-mod-dayz/) have confirmed that DayZ does indeed work with ARMA II Free.

> - **Yes you can in fact download Arma 2 Free and buy Operation Arrowhead and install it to Arma 2 Free.** Then you can already play [DayZ]
> - **The free version has low resolution textures but people say it will work.** Remember, there's no support for the free version, so if something goes wrong.. well you're kind of on your own.

Answer (score 2):

The demo on Steam is Arma 2 Free. If you search Arma 2 Free on Steam, you'll notice that it brings you to the Arma 2 page. The only free download link on that page is the demo link. You'll notice when you click Download demo, it begins installing Arma 2 Free. It may have been something different before 2011.